# update row with additional value only

Tags: mysql

I have a column called tags which includes various tags for an item. It looks like this:

`news,article,sunday,times`

I want to update this to

`news,article,sunday,times,dining`

Is there a way to do it with an update query? For an integer value you can mention in your query `col_name=col_name+100`, is there a way for a string value to do the same?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can use CONCAT(col, ',dining') but it's better not to use comma separated values in a field, it's better to normalize the database

Comment: Yes it is. Use `CONCAT(str1,str2,...) `. But storing values as csv is a very bad db design.

Comment: this looks like bad per design. you sould put them in a separate table and join them.

Comment: Oh didn't know that, thank you very much for your inputs. I will look forward to update my DB design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `concat()` something as

```
update table 
set
tags = concat(tags,',','dining');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I will accept this as soon as I can